# How to search for protected questions

Tags: support, search, protected-questions

How can I search for protected questions?

I want to unprotect questions that shouldn't be protected anymore

Search by filters as Hot (https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month) or interesting (https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) doesn't help

Also search by protected text isn't promising